# Parsing .osm XML data to get Lon/lat coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, parsing, openstreetmap

What's the most efficient parsing method/technique to store, track and associate the associated Nodes and Refs for Polygons while parsing OpenStreetMap (.osm XML) file formats?

This is asked with an iOS Objective-C mobile environment in mind.  Thank you.

Comment: `NSXMLParser` for parsing, `CoreData` for storage. However if your OSM is big, you might consider going straight to `sqlite`.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no pretty good reason, you should rely on the existing work of others and make use of existing OSM XML/PBF parsers that do also some abstraction for you: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks